# Metric rectification using the dual degenerate conic in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, svd

I'm implementing metric rectification of an image with projective distortion in the following manner:

- From the original image I'm finding two sets of parallel lines and finding their intersection points (the vanishing points at infinity).
- I'm selecting five non-collinear points on a circle to be fit to a conic, then I'm checking where that conic intersects the line at infinity using the aforementioned points.
- I use those points to find the distorted dual degenerate conic.

Theoretically, since the distorted conic is determined by C*'=HC*H' (C* is the dual degenerate conic, ' is transpose, H is my homography), I should be able to run SVD to determine H. Undistorted, C* is a 3x3 identity matrix with the last element on the diagonal zero. However, if I run SVD I don't get ones in the diagonal matrix. For some matrices I can avoid this by using Cholesky factorization instead (which factors to C*'=HH' which, at least for this, is mostly okay) but this requires a matrix that's positive definite. Is there a way to distribute the scale inside the diagonal matrix returned in SVD equally into the U and V' matrices while keeping them the same? (e.g. U = V).

I'm using MATLAB for this. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lack of positive definiteness of the resulting matrices is due to noise, as the image used had too much radial distortion rendering even the selection of many points on the circle fairly useless in this approach.

The point missed in the SVD approach was to remove the scale from the diagonal component by right and left multiplying by the square root of the diagonal matrix (with the last diagonal element set to 1, since that singular value should be zero but a zero component there would not yield correct results).